# Different redirect behavior between 2 AEM instances

Tags: aem

I have a page protected with a closed user group. In one AEM instance, if an unauthenticated user tries to access the page, it redirects to the login form, as expected.

In another AEM instance, the user accessing the protected page doesn't get redirected to the login form. Instead the result is a 404.

Here's the access.log for the working instance:

```
10.10.10.10 - - 22/Nov/2016:11:59:01 -0600 "GET /protected-page.html HTTP/1.1" 200 352 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36"
10.10.10.10 - admin 22/Nov/2016:11:59:01 -0600 "GET /system/sling/cqform/defaultlogin.html?resource=%2Fprotected-page.html&$$login$$=%24%24login%24%24 HTTP/1.1" 200 2267 "https://domain.com/protected-page.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36"
```

Here's the access.log for the not working instance:

```
10.10.10.11 - anonymous 22/Nov/2016:12:03:22 -0600 "GET /protected-page.html HTTP/1.1" 404 467 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36"
```

The difference appears to be that the user ID for the working request is -, whereas in the broken one it's anonymous. I think this means that the broken AEM thinks that the user has already been authenticated and just doesn't have access.

Any idea why this is happening and how I can configure the second instance like the first one?

Comment: Ensure that /protected-page really exists on the second publisher! It may happens that the resource get stucked on agent's replication queue. Normally you should get 403 if you try to access a CUG protected page and you should be redirected to the login form

Comment: Thanks, but I verified that it does exist--if the user is already logged in they are correctly taken to the protected page.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that anonymous user has permissions to see the CUG page. You get 404 because the user cannot see that resource at all.